# Linear operators and Markov semigroups

Tags: reference-request, semigroup-of-operators

I was trying to understand the Ergodic theory recently, but I don't really have any knowledge about linear operators, Markov semigroups etc. so I didn't even fully understand the definition.

Could someone recommend a good book, notes or similar resource to learn about Linear operators and Markov semigroups?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.impan.pl/~rams/r48-ladek.pdf) seems to be thorough and well written.